# SQL Management Studio--Implicit conversion from data type datetime to numeric is not allowed

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, dateadd

I am simply attempting to update a table that contains a 'datetype' column, yet when using the dateadd function, I recieve the error of:

```
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to numeric is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

I have searched in many microsoft docs as well as on this site, yet cannot undertand why the error persisits. It should be fairly straightforward but it is not. Both variables are DECLARED as datetime and the simply line of code is right after the comment in the if statement:

```
    DECLARE cur_hours_check CURSOR

FOR
    SELECT Period, Act_Batch_Time, Kg_Per_Hour, Total_QT_Produced, Total_Possible_KG,
            --The columns not affected but need for inserting the shadow day
           Division, Region, Business_Region, Plant, Work_Center, DaysInMonth, Total_Possible_Hours, Demonstrated_Capacity
    FROM zt_Demonstrated_Capacity_Trend
OPEN cur_hours_check

DECLARE             --Cursor Variables Pulling data
    @period                   datetime
,   @act_hours                float
,   @over_hours               float
,   @Total_QT_Produced        float 
,   @KG_per_hour              float
,   @Total_Possible_KG        float
--then the extra
,   @Division                 varchar(20)
,   @Region                   varchar(20)
,   @Business_Region          varchar(20)
,   @Plant                    varchar(40)
,   @Work_Center              varchar(40)
,   @DaysInMonth              int
,   @Total_Possible_Hours     int
,   @Demonstrated_Capacity    float

DECLARE             --Cursor Shadow variables:
    @shadow_period                 datetime 
,   @shadow_act_hours              float
,   @shadow_Total_QT_Produced      float
,   @shadow_Total_Possible_KG      float
,   @shadow_Percent_of_Total_Hours float

DECLARE             --Cursor adjusted first day variables
    @adj_act_hours                 float
,   @adj_Total_QT_Produced         float
,   @adj_Total_Possible_KG         float
,   @adj_Percent_of_Total_Hours    float

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_hours_check
INTO @period, @act_hours, @KG_per_hour, @Total_QT_Produced, @Total_Possible_KG
   ,@Division, @Region, @Business_Region, @Plant, @Work_Center, @DaysInMonth, @Total_Possible_Hours, @Demonstrated_Capacity

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF @act_hours > 24.0
BEGIN
-- Setting the shadow period to carry over values relative to 24 hour time window
    SET @shadow_period = dateadd(d, 1, @period)
    SET @shadow_act_hours = @act_hours - 24.0
    SET @shadow_Total_QT_Produced = @Total_QT_Produced - (@KG_per_hour * @shadow_act_hours)
    SET @shadow_Percent_of_Total_Hours = (@shadow_act_hours/24.0)*100
```

Comment: Could you post some more pieces of your table design and code you are using atm? Where is the declaration of the variables done? Apparently something is not of type `DATETIME`.. :)

Comment: Do you also have the DDL for the table `zt_Demonstrated_Capacity_Trend`? It could be that one of the columns in there is not properly defined.  Do you have specific reasons for using `FLOAT`? Because floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly.

Comment: The issue is on the datetime variables not anything else. Float has no problem

Comment: Which line of code is it flagging as failure? (double click the error it will take you there) I suspect people are looking in the wrong place. It's likely your FETCH that is going over. I bet you have something in the wrong order; so it's trying to put a datetime into a non datetime variable. Also I have tested your dateadd and it is fine.

Comment: @JanineRawnsley That did it!!, it wasn't even on that line 342, I clicked the error and it went to line 347, so the variable was the wrong variable to be used. In the future I shouldn't name everything to such a close degree as it simply adds to the confusion. If you want to add the your answer I will choose it as correct

Comment: That's good news - I sometimes fall into the same trap of looking into completely the wrong place for an error. Just remember to double click errors. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your FETCH that is going over. You have something in the wrong order; so it's trying to put a datetime into a non datetime variable. Also I have tested your dateadd and it is fine.

FYI: You can double click the error to see exactly where the issue is.

Comment: I was about to flag this as not an answer, before I read the comments on the question. You may want to edit your answer to that it no longer gives the impression that you're asking the OP for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add one day to `@period` do the following:

```
SET @shadow_period = DATEADD(day, 1, @period)
```

Comment: Im sorry, I edited the code as I found the updated file, but it still does not work